# Localization not working in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, localization, cakephp-3.x

```
# head -n2 src/Locale/de/default.po
msgid  "route_shop"
msgstr "shop"
```

In my controller, I just have `exit(__('route_shop'));` but it is returning route_shop.

```
ini_get('intl.default_locale'); // returns de (as set in config/bootstrap.php)

'locales' => [APP . 'Locale' . DS] // paths setting in config/app.php
```

Apache/PHP have permissions to the default.po file.  Can't really see anything else that would be wrong.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Have tried different translations, locales, full locale name (de_DE for the folder name/intl.default_locale setting).  No errors reported, nothing in debug.log

Comment: Did you try empting/deleting the caches?

Comment: try removing the extra space between msgid and "route_shop"

Comment: @arilia actually it does.  I deleted the other lines from the file and just tested with route_shop and apparently the two spaces does cause it to fail anywhere in the file, seems like a bug.  Same file works with 1.3 just fine.

Comment: maybe it's a feature. I posted my comment as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem is in the number of spaces between `msgid` and the string.

I don't find any reference but it does not work if there are more than one white space

remove the extra space and remember clearing the cache

Comment: I don't think that it's part of of official [**GNU specs**](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html) or something, CakePHP most probably requires that strict format for performance reasons, [**`substr` is usually faster**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.6/src/I18n/Parser/PoFileParser.php#L91-L94) than a regex or the like.